# Bash script in raspbian runs manually, won't run in cron

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Trying to turn a small TV into a photo frame so to speak, so I have a Raspberry Pi and I have a bash script at /home/pi/scripts/script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/bin/gpicview /home/pi/Downloads/test_5_25.png >> /home/pi/Downloads/test.log
```

My cron tab looks like this:
    `# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * sh /home/pi/scripts/script.sh`

My syslog shows that its running:

```
May 27 04:32:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2999]: (pi) CMD (sh /home/pi/scripts/script.sh
```

But gpicview is not opening like when I run the script manually, and in my error log it shows...

> option parsing failed: Cannot open display:

I thought maybe permissions or something, but I've double checked those to the best of my ability and cannot figure it out. Any clues would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Right now your Cron is run as 'pi' user. Have you tried adding cron as root?

Comment: No luck...
`May 27 04:59:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[3232]: (root) CMD (sh /home/pi/scripts/script.sh)`

Comment: Is there any 'display' parameter that you can pass to gpicview? You can check it in its man page.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the display manually, i.e.:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && sh /home/pi/scripts/script.sh
```

As outlined in [this article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=185993).